# Vue 3 - how to make templates reusable with the Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've just recently migrated my project from Vue 2 to Vue 3, and currently I'm trying to get behind Vue's new Composition API. While I get the concept of Composables etc., there's one use case with the Options API which I haven't been able to figure out how to do with the new API yet.

What I really liked about the Options API's mixins is that they would let met impose additional behaviour on base templates to reuse them in different inheriting components, although I also see the issues they come with. (Note: I just recently found out that `extends` was supposed to be used for this.) Now with the Composition API, I'm not sure how to resolve this use case. Take this example:

`BaseComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="base-template">
        <span @click="baseBar">{{ baseFoo }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: BaseComponent,
        data() {
            return {
                baseFoo: "baseFoo"
            };
        },
        methods: {
            baseBar() {
                alert("baseBar");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`SubComponentA.vue`

```
<script>
    import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent.vue';

    export default {
        name: SubComponentA,
        mixins: [BaseComponent],
        data() {
            return {
                baseFoo: "subFooA"
            };
        },
        methods: {
            baseBar() {
                alert("subBarA");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`SubComponentB.vue`

```
<script>
    import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent.vue';

    export default {
        name: SubComponentB,
        mixins: [BaseComponent],
        data() {
            return {
                baseFoo: "subFooB"
            };
        },
        methods: {
            baseBar() {
                alert("subBarB");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This would let me use both `SubComponentA` and `SubComponentB` independently, with both inheriting from the same base template. So basically, I can reuse the same template in different components, while also being able to work on the base data.

Now I have no idea how to translate this behaviour into the Composition API. While using Composables to import logic from `BaseComponent` into `SubComponentA` is currently the closest I can get, there seems to be no way to export template structures with them, let alone them being bound to the exported logic as well. The only thing I could think of is to resort to a render function, but rebuilding my templates as such would be a major time sink.

So how is this done? Is this even a sensible approach with the Composition API, or may I even have missed some step in rethinking the whole concept?

Comment: I might have found a feasible solution via `defineExpose()` - trying this out on my project right now to check if this fully replaces the use case for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using is to store the component's state into its own module like so:

`BaseState.js`

```
import { ref } from 'vue';

export const baseFoo = ref("baseFoo");
export const baseBar = () => alert("BaseBar");

export function setBaseFoo(newBaseFoo) {
    baseFoo.value = newBaseFoo;
}

export function setBaseBar(newBaseBar) {
    baseBar = newBaseBar;
}
```

`BaseComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="base-template">
        <span @click="baseBar">{{ baseFoo }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { baseFoo, baseBar } from `./BaseState.js`;
</script>
```

`SubComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <BaseComponent />
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    import { setBaseFoo, setBaseBar } from `./BaseState.js`;
    import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent.vue';
    
    setBaseFoo("subFoo");
    setBaseBar(() => alert("subBar"));
</script>
```

Not sure if this is the intended or most elegant solution but it works fine for me.

Alternatively you could use `defineExpose()` to directly access the base component's state logic via template ref, although this solution seems less elegant to me since the sub component won't be able to access state logic outside of `onMounted()`.

`BaseComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="base-template">
        <span @click="baseBar">{{ baseFoo }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const baseFoo = ref("baseFoo");
    const baseBar = () => alert("BaseBar");
    
    defineExpose({baseFoo, baseBar});
</script>
```

`SubComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <BaseComponent ref="base" />
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

    import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent.vue';
    
    const base = ref(null);
    
    onMounted(() => {
        const { baseFoo, baseBar } = base.value;
        
        ...
    });
</script>
```